# Linq to SQL missing records

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql

I'm using views in the DBML, which, for the most part, map to tables.
I have CR view that relates to an EVENTCODE view. I set the context to log the SQL to Console.Out and then ran the SQL generated directly against the DB. I got 3 records back.
But when I run the select in Linq to SQL (setting LoadOptions on the context to tie in the EVENTCODE table), I only have 1 record in CR.EVENTCODEs.
The tie between the views is correct (same as in the db). I can call context.EVENTCODEs.Where... and I get 3 records back as well. But pulling the related EVENTCODE records through the CR object returns only 1.
What else should I check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the field identified as the Primary Key on the EVENTCODE view did not uniquely identify records in the view. The 3 records coming back all had the same key value, so the EntitySet was adding the first record, and disregarding the subsequent records because they had the same key as the one in the set.
I changed the view to use a combined key (across 4 fields) and now the related records number 3.